# Error when I use app-compact v7 in my project for using tool bar

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am getting an error when I try to add a toolbar to my application using following code

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements 
IChangeFragementListener {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

private ListView mDrawerList;

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

ArrayList<String> mGroupItem = new ArrayList<String>();

private boolean mReInstance;
ImageView menu_iconImageView;
int flag=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setGroupData();
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

My toolbar.xml is

```
<Toolbar 
android:id="@+id/tool"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#819FF7"
android:elevation="4dp"
   />
```

And the error shown is

> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14 01-29 13:34:46.336: E/AndroidRuntime (16928): at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelega 01-29 13:34:46.336: E/AndroidRuntime (16928): at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:117) 01-29 13:34:46.336: E/AndroidRuntime (16928): at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:456)

Comment: extend `AppCompactActiivty`. `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

Comment: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
01-29 13:34:46.336: E/AndroidRuntime(16928):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelega
01-29 13:34:46.336: E/AndroidRuntime(16928):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:117)
01-29 13:34:46.336: E/AndroidRuntime(16928):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:456)

Comment: I am adding two other jar file

Comment: android-support-v4 and android-support-v13

Comment: post the stacktrace in your question by editing it

Comment: @AnilRanga Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Yes. He's using eclipse.

Comment: @KNeerajLal yes sir I am using eclipse

Comment: @AnilRanga I think it is time to move to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    android:id="@+id/tool"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#819FF7"
    android:elevation="4dp" />
```

Comment: 01-29 14:02:32.336: E/dalvikvm(21515): Could not find class 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23', referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create
v14,and v7

Comment: do you have the latest version of support v7 in the gradle file?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: sir still shown this error after adding above code clean and build .

Comment: 01-29 14:24:28.126: E/AndroidRuntime(25049): Process: com.swaadmarket.food, PID: 25049
01-29 14:24:28.126: E/AndroidRuntime(25049): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
01-29 14:24:28.126: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:135)

Comment: Hmm.. Hope this post to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384935/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-app-appco

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960842/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-app-appcompatdelegateimplv14

Answer (score 0):

your toolbar layout should be like this,
as you are trying use support library v-7

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

code would be something like this

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_custom_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

this Toolbar  is supposed to be imported from here

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,
```

Kindly pay attention `ActionBarActivity` has been [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) use `AppCompatActivity` to subclass your activity

Comment: sir when I use app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" its shown error like perfix parse error

Comment: sir I am using my toolbar in this layout <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" > <Toolbar 
android:id="@+id/tool"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#819FF7"
android:elevation="4dp"
   /> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: @AnilRanga, in your layout you are starting tag writting <Toolbar, but you have to start that with <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, as you are using support library

Comment: sir I have changed tool bar like this  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: @AnilRanga, have a look at this code, https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nimgade/pk/mytutorialapplication/MainActivity.java